# Is there a reason to use SVG when not in need scaling "up" an image?

Tags: image, svg, jpeg

I talked to a programmer. He said it was absolutely neccessary to use SVG for **all** graphic elements on a web-page for best result. I I have a jpg image that does not need to scale up  (that is about 500px width and 200px height). It would only have to scale down when coming to mobile devices. Would replacing this jpg with svg do any effect? Would it really be better?

Comment: jpg is a raster image. doing it as an svg would be pointless. it'd just be a blown up raster image, and suffer from all the problems that blowup produces.

Comment: what do you mean by blowup?

Comment: scaling the image. e.g. stretching from 100x100 -> 300x300. all you're doing is blowing up pixels, and get bigger pixels. svg is a vector format, jpg is raster.

Comment: I understand that they get "blown up" when stretching a jpg, but when using svg-format it will keep it's "smoothness" and not get pixelated. That's in my point of view the main reason why to use svg. But when having an image like 300x300 you would never have to enlarge if it's just an "ordinary website". That's why I'm asking why svg always would be better then jpg.

Comment: svg isn't a "picture". it's a series of instructions on how to DRAW a picture. "line from point X to point Y", flood fill area X with color Y", etc... since it's all just coordinates and instructions. it's basically scalable to any size. it's the difference between a song in mp3 format and a song in sheet music format. you can't change the tempo of the mp3 without distorting the song, but it's easy to record a new song by changing the tempo instruction on the sheet music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use svg in all images.
SVG is a vector format, best suitable for icons or other relatively simple images.

Comment: But even if they are simple. What's the befinit when they only need to scale down? I understand if you need to scale up an image.

Comment: I would use SVG only if my assets are already in that format. SVG can be smaller than PNG, but you cannot know it before without converting original image to SVG.